# When is the graph of a morphism between smooth projective varieties nef?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a morphism between smooth projective varieties over an algebraic closed field. The graph of $f$ namely $\Gamma_f$ is a cycle inside $X \times Y$. When is $\Gamma_f$ nef? When is it a complete intersection of ample divisors? Are there some useful criterions or restrictions?

If $X=Y$ and $f=id$ then this is a problem about the diagonal cycle, for example in the curve case the diagonal is ample iff genus of $X$ is zero. How about the surface or threefold case?

In the general morphism case with $Y$ being a curve (or just $\mathbb P^1$), the graph is a divisor, maybe the property can be described in a simple way.

Comment: @abx Is this obvious? Do you have a reference? It's clear for the case of curves, but what about the higher dimensional case?

Comment: This paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.08659) of Lehmann and Ottem certainly seems relevant.

Comment: @Yosemite Stan: you are right, I was too hasty. I delete my comment.